# updating a notification service from activity

Tags: android, service, notifications

I have a **notification service** that starts when application is started
and there are 2 buttons in **main activity**, I want to update notification by clicking on each buttons, foreample if I touch start button, the text view in notification service should show: you touched start button and ..

I want to update notification from my activity
how should I do that?

here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn_start,btn_end;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    btn_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
    btn_end = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_end);


    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationService.class);
    serviceIntent.setAction("startforeground");
    startService(serviceIntent);


}
public class NotificationService extends Service {
Notification status;
public static int FOREGROUND_SERVICE = 101;

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    if (intent.getAction().equals("startforeground")) {
        showNotification();
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

private void showNotification() {
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.status_bar);
    RemoteViews bigViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.status_bar_expanded);
    status = new Notification.Builder(this).build();
    status.contentView = views;
    status.bigContentView = bigViews;
    status.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    status.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    startForeground(FOREGROUND_SERVICE, status);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to use same way as you create one and then update it with whatever you need by using this method:

NotificationManagerCompat.notify()

Read the details here:
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification

You need to use the same Notification id for when creating and when updating.